# AWS Amplify objects not being stored to database occasionally

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-amplify

I built a reactJS frontend web-app with Amplify Studio to run the backend.

We create an object Symptom and then attach object References to it. In testing, when I run it this works 100/100 times.

```
const handleSave = async ({symptomID, frequencyField, fullSymptomName, bodySystemIds, snippets}) => {
    const symptom = new Symptom({
        "symptomID": Number(symptomID),
        "frequency": frequencyField,
        "bodySystems": bodySystemIds,
        "symptomName": fullSymptomName,
        "Snippets": []
    })
    
const newSnippets = snippets.map((snippet) => {
    return new Snippet({
      text: snippet.text,
      title: snippet.title,
      symptomID: symptom.id,
      referenceID: snippet.refId,
    });
  });
  console.log('NewSnippets length:')
  console.log(newSnippets.length)

  await DataStore.save(symptom)

    const saveSnippets = newSnippets.map((snippet) => DataStore.save(snippet))
    Promise.all(saveSnippets)
        .then(() => (console.log('All posts saved successfully'), setAddingSymptom(false)))
        .catch((error) => console.error('Error saving posts:', error));
}
```

The snippets array can be long, it can be up to 10 or 15 items.

The problem arises when another tester tries to work with it. Then occasionally only 2 or 3 items are saved. However, the test user will see the snippets being added in the interface, so they are saved in the local cache. They just never make it to the database.

Any ideas?